# Javascript: match() is returning non-matching text after the pattern matched substring

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract all of the hyperlinks out of a large HTML file using
javascript in the nodejs command line console.

match() is extracting the hyperlinks, but also returning non matching text after it.

For example:

```
Text before the link <a href="http:\\angst.org/frustration/pita1.html class=\"outlink\">PITA 1</a> the text after the link.`
```

Sample result:

```
<a href="http:\\angst.org/frustration/pita1.html class=\"outlink\">PITA 1</a> the text after the link.
```

Interestingly, when I took one of textArray lines/strings, wrapped it in back
ticks and set it to a variable the code below worked fine.  I would get just what I want only:

```
<a href="http:\\angst.org/frustration/pita1.html class=\"outlink\">PITA 1</a>
```

**This is the javascript I am using:**

```
// is an html file, input code removed for clarity of this example
var text;  

// Split the html file into lines
const textArray = text.split("\n");

// Regexp pattern to match the links
var p = /<a href=\"http:\/\/angst.org\/frustration\/(.+)\.html\" class=\"outlink\">(.+)<\/a>/;

// Extract and output all of the hyperlinks
for (let i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    resultArray = textArray[i].match(p);
    console.log(resultArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: I've run your code and it seems to match only the <a></a> tag as intended.

Comment: To me the example's link-markup seems to be invalid at the `href` attribute. Nevertheless, I came up with [`/<a\s+href=(?<quote>['"])https?:\\\\angst.org\/frustration\/(?<filename>.*?)\.html\k<quote>.*?>(?<content>.*?)<\/a>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/kZw1gp/1) which matches file-name and text-content from any valid link-markup.

Comment: Alternatively you could import https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-jsdom. This gives you a DOM and allows you using  `document.querySelectorAll('a')` conveniently.